# Not able to publish in Sitecore 82

Tags: sitecore

I am not able to publish in sitecore 82 website. If i disable "Set Xdb.Enabled to false and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled to false." these keys, how would Experience analytics work in that case ? Can anyone let me know the solution to publish ?

Comment: When you publish what error do you get?

Comment: Can you check the logs and post the actual error you get while publishing ?